# Highcharts with multipe Series

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with a Y axis as a percentage (0-100%) and the X axis multiple separate stacks. The data for each stack is independent and has no relationship to the other stacks.

e.g.

```
Stack 1 = Animals [10, 20, 30 , 40]
Stack 2 = Cars [10, 30]
Stack 3 = Aeroplanes [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
```

Is this achievable?

This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/carlskii/f3EK8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each series, you can set `stack: id`

Like this:

```
        series: [{
            stack: 'aeroplanes',
            name: 'Prop Planes',
            data: [25],
            color: 'green'
        }]
```

Stacks with the same ID will be grouped together.